# Exception 1 Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a code that if a do click on login with Facebook button works ok and prints me the correct data that I expect... Now the thing is that if I reload throws me the exception "Exception 1: This authorization code has been used."

There´s my `callback.php` code

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
            'app_id'                  => $this->app_id,
            'app_secret'              => $this->app_secret,
            'cookie'                  => true,
            'status'                  => true,
            'default_graph_version'   => 'v2.10',
            'http_client_handler'     => 'curl', // can be changed to stream or guzzle
            'persistent_data_handler' => 'session', // make sure session has started
        ));

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
            $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
        }

        try {
            // get access token
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            print_r($accessToken);
            // save access token to persistent data store
            $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('access_token', $accessToken);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // error occured
            echo 'Exception 1: ' . $e->getMessage() . '
    ';
        }

        // get stored access token
        $accessToken = $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->get('access_token');

        if ($accessToken && !$accessToken->isExpired()) {
            // set default access_token so we can use it in any requests
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you try searching for that error? there are a lot of stackoverflow threads about it already.

Comment: Yes, I seach about it but no one help me... Have anyone or idea?

Comment: Simply redirect somewhere else after successful login, so that the code parameter disappears from the URL ...